# vba if statement error

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I was working with below code but it shows error when I try to delete entire column (Multiple cells) from the worksheet at once. the code works fine with the if statement it just I cant delete all "M" & "I" characters at once from the sheet.
Below is the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
If Target.Column = 18 Then
    ThisRow = Target.Row
    If Target.Value = "M" Then
        Range("AB" & ThisRow) = "NA"
    ElseIf Target.Value = "I" Then
     Range("AB" & ThisRow) = ""
    Else
    Range("AB" & ThisRow) = ""
    End If
    If Target.Value = "M" Then
        Range("AC" & ThisRow) = "NA"

    ElseIf Target.Value = "I" Then
     Range("AC" & ThisRow) = ""
    Else
    Range("AC" & ThisRow) = ""
    End If
        End If
End Sub
```

**Updated code**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim r As Integer, lastRow As Integer

If (Not Target.Column = 24) Then Exit Sub
If (Target.Columns.Count > 1) Then Exit Sub

lastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For r = Target.Row To Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1
    Range("Z" & r & ",AA" & r & ",AB" & r & ",AC" & r) = IIf(Cells(r, 24) = "Yes", "NA", "")
    Range("Y" & r & ",Z" & r & ",AA" & r & ",AB" & r & ",AC" & r & ",AD" & r) = IIf(Cells(r, 24) = "No", "NA", "")
    If (r = lastRow) Then Exit Sub
Next r
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: What is the error thrown and which line causes it?

Comment: This line(`ElseIf Target.Value = "I" Then`) has no purpose; Your code says if the Target cell's value is M, replace AB/AC with "NA", otherwise replace it with "".  You don't need that `ElseIf` if the output from the `Else` is the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can escape the code when the entire target column is deleted by inserting this line before your first If statement:

```
If (Target.Rows.Count > 1) Then Exit Sub
```

You can also simplify the code by updating both target cells simultaneously and using an `IIF` statement to calculate the value:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Byte
    If (Target.Rows.Count > 1) Then Exit Sub

    If Target.Column = 18 Then
        r = Target.Row
        Range("AB" & r & ",AC" & r) = IIf(Target.Value = "M", "NA", "")
    End If
End Sub
```

**Update** to edit multiple rows:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Integer, lastRow As Integer

    If (Not Target.Column = 18) Then Exit Sub
    If (Target.Columns.Count > 1) Then Exit Sub

    lastRow = Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For r = Target.Row To Target.Row + Target.Rows.Count - 1
        Range("AB" & r & ",AC" & r) = IIf(Cells(r, 18) = "M", "NA", "")
        ' repeat above line for further checks
        Range("AE" & r & ",AF" & r) = IIf(Cells(r, 18) = "S", "NA", "")

        If (r = lastRow) Then Exit Sub
    Next r
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works fine but when I remove the values like  "M" it should also delete the cells which have been filled. Means after deleting it all filled cells should be blank as well.

Comment: Also can I know if I need to add one more validation apart from "M" i.e. for "S" for different cells to highlight "NA" what changes do I need to make in that above code?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Are the _different cells_ the target or source? If you want to create a separate list (i.e. a different target) when column R contains the value "S", then copy the first line within the For Loop, insert it immediately afterwards and update the values.  If you want the output in the same list, you can just add the new condition to the IIF condition, such as `IIf(Cells(r, 18) = "M" OR Cells(r, 18) = "S", "NA", "")`.

Comment: Yes I need to put "S" in column R the cells with "NA" will be different for it, it wont be "AB" & "AC".

Comment: Updated update to create a similar list in columns AE and AF where "S" is shown in column R.

Comment: Yes, that is what your original `IF` statement indicates.  `If Target.Value = "M" Then [output "NA"] Else [output ""]`.  If the target value is "S" it is, therefore, not "M" and it will output "" to the respective list.  You confirmed in your comment that where "S" is present in column R then a different list should be modified.  Please clarify what you actually want.

Comment: Sorry if I confused with my question.. To be clear. I want to add either "M" or "S" in column R, If I enter "M" then cells AB and AC should get changed to NA and when I change that value to "S" in column R cells AB and AC should get cleared and new cells should reflect NA( It can be cells AB and AC or any other cells as well).

Comment: That describes how the code works. I can't see a difference between what you want and how the code works. Have you copied the code precisely?

Comment: I have updated the code, please have look to that. Its only working for "No" validation. Let me know if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: Because your output range is the same, the line that checks for "No" is overwriting the output for the previous line. I will tweak the code (when I get to my PC) and get back to you.

Comment: OK, here's your answer: change the first two rows in the For Loop to `Range("Y" & r & ":AD" & r) = IIf(Cells(r, 24) = "No", "NA", "")` and `If (Cells(r, 24) = "Yes") Then Range("Z" & r & ":AC" & r) = "Yes"` in that order. The first of these lines represents a wider range, so use that to clear all of the relevant cells if neither condition is matched.  The second uses a basic If statement because you don't want to do anything if the condition is not matched (which is not an option using IIF).  Lastly, as the target rows are adjacent, you don't need to specify every cell, just use "Y"&r&":AD"&r.